# Modifying jquery function

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Below I am using jquery to toggle display divs. What do I need to add to this to have only the first result to be active when the page loads?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
$(".toggle_container").hide(); 

//Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
$("h6.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first match from the original selection using the [`eq()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method or the [`first()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method.

```
$("h6.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
}).eq(0).click();
 // ^------^------grab the first element, and trigger the handler
```

---

Or as an alternative, you can use the [`triggerHandler()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) method to trigger only the first one.

```
$("h6.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
}).triggerHandler('click');
 // -----^--------this will only trigger the click on the first element.
```

---

Both of these allow you to utilize the original DOM selection, preventing the need to re-select.

Comment: is there a way not to animate the first match? so that way its already active when the page loads

Comment: @mwimwi76: Instead of triggering the handler, you could do something like this: `.eq(0).addClass("active").next().show();` Or you could just add the class, and not hide the first container to begin with. `$(".toggle_container").slice(1).hide();` *(hide all but the first container)* `$("h6.trigger").click(function(){/*..*/}).eq(0).addClass('active');` *(add the active class to the first element)*

Answer (score 0):

You could just raise the click event you registered on the first h6 matched:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
$(".toggle_container").hide(); 

//Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
$("h6.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});

$("h6.trigger:first").trigger('click');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
 $("h6.trigger:first").addClass('active');
});
```

Also, that goes instead of `$(document).ready(function(){})`, since `.ready()` is an old jquery way of doing something on document load.